# Connecting fiber sequences for classifying spaces

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, exact-sequence, classifying-spaces

My original question was:

> Is there a long exact sequence for classifying spaces of topological
> groups?

It is solved by a comment from @JHF , since $BA$ is not usually a group. The sequence cannot go *long* enough in general.

The following are still puzzling to me.

I am reading the book *Basic Bundle Theory and K-Cohomology Invariants* ([springer webpage](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-540-74956-1)). On page 140, there goes a sequence
$$\mathbb{Z/2}\rightarrow Spin(n) \rightarrow SO(n) \xrightarrow{\sigma} B(\mathbb{Z/2})\, ,$$
where $B$ is for taking classifying sapce of a topological group, $\mathbb{Z/2}$ is a $2$-element group. I guess the map $\sigma$ is a classifying map here.

The author then claims that $\sigma$ is a group homomorphism and apply the fiber sequence again to produce
$$B(\mathbb{Z/2})\rightarrow BSpin(n) \rightarrow BSO(n) \xrightarrow{B\sigma} B^2(\mathbb{Z/2}) \, . $$

The group structure of $B(\mathbb{Z/2})$ comes from the functoriality of $B$ and the Abelian group structure of $\mathbb{Z/2}$.

A similar sequence is later refered to as a *classifying space sequence* in that book at page 284.

There are some related posts like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/398616/), which shows that for good cases, $B$ is exact in the sense that it sends a short exact sequence to a fibration. My question is why $\sigma$ here is a group homomorphism and how it "connects" the two short sequences.

In the book *Spin Geometry* by Lawson and Michelsohn, a statement for the "exactness" of $B$ (page 84) seems to come from the exact sequence of cohomology groups. I also wonder why it is true and whether it gives the "connecting map" between two sequences mentioned above. I know a result that cohomology classes can be represented by mappings into Eilenberg-MacLane spaces up to homotopy.

Comment: For $n \geq 2$, $B^n A$ doesn't usually make sense unless $A$ is an abelian group.

Comment: @JHF Thank you for pointing it out. I would edit my question a little.